# __init__ variable manipulation in python oop object

Tags: python, oop

```py
import math

class calculator():
  def __init__(self):
    self.dictionary = {"+": lambda x, y: x + y,
                       "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
                       "*": lambda x, y: x * y,
                       "/": lambda x, y: x / y}

  def add_operation(self,symbol,function):
    if symbol not in self.dictionary:
      self.dictionary[symbol]=function

  def calculate(self, num1, symbol, num2):
    if symbol not in self.dictionary:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operation symbol")

    if not (isinstance(num1, (int, float)) and isinstance(num2, (int, float))):
        raise ValueError("Invalid input numbers")
    num1 = float(input("What's the first number? "))
    num2 = float(input("What's the second number? "))

    return self.dictionary[symbol](num1, num2)
calc=calculator()
calc.add_operation("sqrt",lambda x: math.sqrt(x))
calc.add_operation("exponentiation", lambda x, y: math.pow(x, y))
calc.add_operation("logarithm", lambda x: math.log(x))
print(calc.dictionary)

while True:
   calc = calculator()
   num1 = float(input("What is the first number? "))
   num2 = float(input("What is the second number? "))
   symbol = input("What operation would you like to perform? ")

   result = calc.calculate(num1, symbol, num2)
   print("Result:", result)

   new_op = input("Would you like to perform another calculation? ")
   if new_op == "no":
      break
```

this is supposed to be a calculator that is initiated with the four basic calculation operations and then through the add_operation method i should add more advanced operations such as square root but i always get the input a valid operation error

Comment: `calculate` takes two numbers as arguments; why is it using `input` to ignore them and get new numbers?

Comment: Why do you create a new instance of `calculator` each time through the loop, instead of reusing the same instance for multiple calculations?

Comment: What *are* you inputing for the operation that you get an invalid operation error?

Comment: The `calc` instance created in the `while` loop doesn't know about sqrt, exponentiation or logarithm, because you added those to a different instance of the class.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but instead of `lambda x: math.sqrt(x)` you can write simply `math.sqrt`. And similar for `math.pow` and `math.log`.

Comment: @chepner numbers are supposed to be user given, also thanks for noting that mistake with calculator reuse in each loop, i've just been coding for 12 hours straight and i guess i just didnt notice it lol

Comment: Please post the full error message including the full traceback message. You give us a summary of an error message so I can't even search for that phrase to see the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems

1. You are generating a new instance of the calculator in the while loop, a new instance of the calculator does not know about the additional functions
2. Taking input again in the calculate function, you are passing arguments already so no need to take the inputs again
3. Not handling multiple arguments for sqrt and log functions. The second input is not getting used and the lambda function will throw an error if you are passing 2 arguments.

The simplest fixed solution is

```
import math


class calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = {
            "+": lambda x, y: x + y,
            "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
            "*": lambda x, y: x * y,
            "/": lambda x, y: x / y,
        }

    def add_operation(self, symbol, function):
        if symbol not in self.dictionary:
            self.dictionary[symbol] = function

    def calculate(self, num1, symbol, num2):
        print(num1, symbol, num2)
        print(self.dictionary.keys())
        if symbol not in self.dictionary:
            raise ValueError("Invalid operation symbol")

        if not (isinstance(num1, (int, float)) and isinstance(num2, (int, float))):
            raise ValueError("Invalid input numbers")
        # num1 = float(input("What's the first number? "))
        # num2 = float(input("What's the second number? "))

        return self.dictionary[symbol](num1, num2)


calc = calculator()
calc.add_operation("sqrt", lambda x, y: math.sqrt(x))
calc.add_operation("exponentiation", lambda x, y: math.pow(x, y))
calc.add_operation("logarithm", lambda x, y: math.log(x))
print(calc.dictionary)

while True:
    # calc = calculator()
    num1 = float(input("What is the first number? "))
    num2 = float(input("What is the second number? "))
    symbol = input("What operation would you like to perform? ")

    result = calc.calculate(num1, symbol, num2)
    print("Result:", result)

    new_op = input("Would you like to perform another calculation? ")
    if new_op == "no":
        break
```